# How to create a linspace like pytorch tensor which ensures that all values are between start and stop?

Tags: python, floating-point, pytorch, precision, rounding-error

I want to create a 1d tensor of values similar to `torch.linspace` or `torch.arange` in pytorch, which ensures that all values of the created tensor are between start and stop.

Example values which break my assertion:

```
>>> start = torch.tensor(3.197054147720337, dtype=torch.float)
>>> stop = torch.tensor(11, dtype=torch.float)
>>> num_samples = 8
```

So the `result_tensor` should pass this test:

```
>>> assert (start <= result_tensor).all() and (result_tensor <= stop).all()
```

But unfortunately, neither the `linspace` solution fulfills this requirement:

```
>>> result_tensor = torch.linspace(start.item(), stop.item(), num_samples)
>>> result_tensor[-1] - stop
torch.tensor(9.5367e-07)
```

Nor does the `arange` solution:

```
>>> step = (stop - start) / (num_samples - 1)
>>> result_tensor = torch.arange(num_samples, dtype=torch.float) * step + start
>>> result_tensor[-1] - stop
torch.tensor(9.5367e-07)
```

In both possibilties, the biggest value of the `result_tensor` is slightly higher than stop.
Is there a way to ensure this requirement for all numbers without doing explicit value clipping?

(Gradientes are not required. A vectorizeable solution like the one with `torch.arange` is preferable, but not a must.`start`, `stop`, `between`, `step` could be matrices where the last dimension is of size 1 and is broadcasted to `num_samples`)

Comment: can you use `torch.clamp()`?

Comment: the solution i use at the moment is ```torch.min()``` and broadcasting the tensor ```stop``` to ```result_tensor```, because it's vectoriced for different ```stop``` values.
This solution is ok, but i thought that there could be another/better solution, for example using floating point arithmetics

Answer (score 0):

I came across the similar issue, the following helped me.

```
import torch
start = 3.197054147720337
stop = 11
num_samples = 8
step = (stop - start) / num_samples
result_tensor = torch.arange(start, stop, step)
assert (start <= result_tensor).all() and (result_tensor <= stop).all()
print(result_tensor.shape)
print(result_tensor)
```

[image: Reference Output]